# Change of coordinates in vector field

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\phi=(x_1, x_2)$ be a map of $R^2$ and let $X=x_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+x_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}$. I am trying to find a map $\psi=(y_1,y_2)$ so that $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1}$.

So far, I have used the chain rule to obtain $X=X(y_1)\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1}+X(y_2)\frac{\partial}{\partial y_2}$, so $X(y_1)=1$ and $X(y_2)=0$. Solving this yields $(y_1, y_2) = (\frac{1}{2}ln(x^2+y^2)+c_1, c_2)$. Is this a solution to the problem? The part that I am not certain about is whether the map $\psi$ that I have obtained indeed gives  $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1}$. Also, do the constants matter? If yes, how are they determined (as no initial conditions are given)?

Comment: what is $\phi$! exactly!, you should write sth like: $\phi: X \rightarrow Y; \phi(x) = \dots $

Comment: You obviously have to restrict to the complement of the origin (why?). Big hint: Spherical coordinates. Comment: it's far easier to translate into differential forms. Note that $\sum x_i\,dx_i = d(\frac12\|x^2\|)$.

Answer (score 1):

I infer that you mean $\phi$ and $\psi$ to be coordinate charts on $\mathbb R^2$.

Expressing the components of the vector fields $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ in terms of $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$, you get
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}=\sum_j\frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}.$$

So
$$
\sum_i X(y^j)\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}
=X
=\sum_i X(x^i)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}
= \sum_{i,j} X(x^i)\frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j},
$$

and hence the componennts of $X$ in terms of $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$ are

$$
X(y^j)
= \sum_{i} X(x^i)\frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^i}.
$$

So in order to verify that what you got is what you want, you need to calculate the jacobian matrix $\frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^i}$, perform the summation with $X(x^i)$ and see if you get $X(y^1)=1$ and $X(y^2)=0$. Can you finish?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I label my coordinates with superscripts instead of subscripts. I hope it doesn't bother you too much.

Comment: Kakkiuz Yes, I have already done this and I get both equalities. But what about the constants? Are they of no consequence?

Comment: how do you explain your 1st centered formula?

Comment: @GeorgeK Yes. As you observed, the constants have no effect in the resulting vector field. This is similar to how the speed of a parametrized curve is unaffected by a translation in the parameter.

Comment: @janmarqz The formula
$$X=\sum_jX(y^j)\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$$
is valid for every vector field $X$ and coordinate chart $(y^1,y^2)$. Now subsitute $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$.